# What tx_buf expects as input in spi_transfer

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, watchdog, spi

I am lookig into a code which is writing some data on SPI line,using spi_transfer structure

```
struct spi_transfer  
 {
 const void * tx_buf;
 void * rx_buf;
 unsigned len;
 dma_addr_t tx_dma;
 dma_addr_t rx_dma;
 unsigned cs_change:1;
 u8 bits_per_word;
 u16 delay_usecs;
 u32 speed_hz;
 struct list_head transfer_list;
};
```

Now some like this is been done in Code

```
u8 *cmd
cmd=kmalloc(3,GFP_KERNEL);
cmd[0]=16;
cmd[1]=32;
```

Now t[0].tx_buf = cmd;

now I am wondering what is being written into this buffer and what tx_buf expects here??
We are writng to some watch dog counter through SPI line.

Comment: `cmd` holds the pointer to the data. And this pointer is assigned to the `tx_buf` which is supposed to `point` to the transmit data. Hence, now `tx_buf` is pointing to the transmit data.

Comment: So what is being written on the spi line first ,is it a value 16 written on line first

Comment: You'll have to look into the code where it is writing to SPI's data buffer(transmit data register). Because this is not writing anything to SPI it is just pointing to the data which is to be written.

Comment: It will depend on how the transaction is started. It seems an object of `spi_transfer` is passed on to some function, which internally does the write to SPI.

Comment: I guess you are right @Uchia ,can see spi_message_add_tail() and spi_sync() calls but couldn't find their defination in my code base,looks like its dynamic modules loded at runtime

Comment: Yes, because at the end somefunction has to take that data `object`, extract the `tx_data` and write it to the `spi_data` register to transmit the data. Depending on the architecture either 8-bits or 16-bits can be written into the `txFifo`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are sending bytes 0x10, 0x20, 0x00 to the SPI device. There should be other code which has defined and initialized the rest of the struct spi_transfer t[]. Notably, t[0].len must be set to 3.

Perhaps your code base is for a kernel module / device driver. Functions spi_message_add_tail() etc. are in kernel source include/linux/spi/spi.h. They are not dynamic modules, but your module will be linked with kernel when your module is loaded.

Check kernel source for examples of SPI infrastructure use, e.g. drivers/base/regmap/regmap-spi.c.

Comment: t[0].len=1 is set in our code ,Could you please let me know what it do??

Comment: That will send just one byte, value 0x10. It is unclear why your code would touch cmd[1]. From the Code you included "kmalloc(3..." it appeared that len would be 3. 
Here is excerpt from kernel source
`* struct spi_transfer - a read/write buffer pair
 * tx_buf: data to be written (dma-safe memory), or NULL
...
 * len: size of rx and tx buffers (in bytes)`